# get item from list of dictionaries

Tags: robotframework

I have a list of dictionaries, and I would like to get the one that have a particular item in a particular key:

```
[
  {
    'id': 4,
    'name': 'Mary',
    'age': 21
  }, {
    'id': 6
    'name': 'John'
    'age': 26
  }, {
    'id': 7
    'name': 'Peter'
    'age': 31
  }, {
    'id': 9
    'name': 'Maks'
    'age': 50
  }
]
```

Now I would like to get the dictionary for id = x.

The only way I see to do it is iterate the list and break the for when the item is found,  but then the x is not in the list it and I don't know how to return the item

```
:FOR    ${item}    IN    @{list} 
\  Exit for loop if  Should be equals as integers  ${item['id']}  6
```

How can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it:

```
:FOR    ${item}    IN    @{list} 
\  Exit for loop if  Should be equals as integers  ${item['id']}  6
\  Return from keyword if  ${item['id']} == 6  ${item}
Fail  id not found in list
```